Special treatement NA values in a dataframe
I have one dataframe and 2 functions:
My dataframe:
s_name      <-c("john","paul","george","ringo","mick","ron")
s_words     <-c("one","two","three",NA,"five","six")
n_units     <-c(3,2,2,4,1,5)
n_price    <-c(12,13,90,21,80,5)
df1 <- data.frame(s_name,s_words,n_units,n_price) 

> df1
  s_name s_words n_units n_price
1   john     one       3      12
2   paul     two       2      13
3 george   three       2      90
4  ringo    <NA>       4      21
5   mick    five       1      80
6    ron     six       5       5

My  func1:
f_na1 <- function (s_string) {
  n_len = nchar(s_string)
  s_label = paste("size",n_len,"chars")
  return(s_label)
}

My  func2:
f_na2 <- function (s_string) {
  if(is.na(s_string)) {
    return("_na_")
  } else {
    n_len = nchar(s_string)
    s_label = paste("size",n_len,"chars")
    return(s_label)
  }
}

When apply my first function:
df1$s_result=f_na1(df1$s_words)

My result 1 is:
> df1
  s_name s_words n_units n_price      s_result
1   john     one       3      12  size 3 chars
2   paul     two       2      13  size 3 chars
3 george   three       2      90  size 5 chars
4  ringo    <NA>       4      21 size NA chars
5   mick    five       1      80  size 4 chars
6    ron     six       5       5  size 3 chars

That is ok
But When apply my second function:
df1$s_result=f_na2(df1$s_words)

My result 2 is:
> df1$s_result=f_na2(df1$s_words)
Error in if (is.na(s_string)) { : the condition has length > 1

I would expect the following:
> df1
  s_name s_words n_units n_price      s_result
1   john     one       3      12  size 3 chars
2   paul     two       2      13  size 3 chars
3 george   three       2      90  size 5 chars
4  ringo    <NA>       4      21          _na_
5   mick    five       1      80  size 4 chars
6    ron     six       5       5  size 3 chars

How can I get the last result?
Thanks in advance.
I'm begginer in R Language.

is.na(s_string) returns a vector.

if (all(is.na(s_string))) will resolve the error.  As the comment above notes that you are testing a vector, ie, multiple values.  Some of those values may be NA.  Some may not be NA.  so the if() statement doesn't know what to do.  all() or any() are often used in this type of situation to test the condition of a vector

Try f_na2 <- function (s_string) { ifelse(is.na(s_string), "_na_", paste("size",nchar(s_string),"chars")) }. if is for control flow where you have a single test. ifelse is a vectorized function where the input and output are vectors.

Ok, thanks a lot:

df1$new=ifelse(is.na(df1$s_word),"na",paste("size",nchar(df1$s_word),"chars") )


df1
s_name s_words n_units n_price          new
1   john     one       3      12 size 3 chars
2   paul     two       2      13 size 3 chars
3 george   three       2      90 size 5 chars
4  ringo           4      21         na
5   mick    five       1      80 size 4 chars
6    ron     six       5       5 size 3 chars

